# Has something changed in Drive file permissions resources (January 2019)?

Tags: google-drive-api

My program has started misbehaving for some users, and I've tracked it to the info provided by Drive in file permission resource calls.

I haven't found anything specific at developers.google.com etc, but I know they're rushing out some API changes if not now then soon?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @jess Thanks, I knew this was a terrible question - I was just hoping to provoke a reaction from someone at Google (this being their dev 'support' site) if something had actually changed. I'll delete it in a day or so.